# Using a text file instead of an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm pretty new to Javascript and I want to know if it's possible to use an uploaded .txt file or .csv file to replace the following array;

The reason I'd like to use a .txt. or .csv file is because there are acually hundreds of post codes which I get daily and updates the post codes or removes the post codes (if they are older than 90 days). I'd rather not edit the array daily.

```
    if (isInArray(pcode, [2000, 2001, 2100, 2010, 3100, 3131, 3123, 3333, 3215, 4100, 4321, 4567, 4865, 5000]) !== -1) {
    pcheck = "Delivered";
} else {
    pcheck = "Not delivered";
}
```

This is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter the Post Code:

<input id="code" value="" />

<button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>

<p id="result"></p>
<p id="state"></p>

<script>
function isInArray(value,array) {
return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

function validate() {
var pcode, pcheck, pstate;
pcode = Number(document.getElementById("code").value);
if (isNaN(pcode)) {
    pcheck = "This is not a post code.";
    pstate = "No state.";
}

if (isInArray(pcode, [2000, 2001, 2100, 2010, 3100, 3131, 3123, 3333, 3215, 4100, 4321, 4567, 4865, 5000]) !== -1) {
    pcheck = "Delivered";
} else {
    pcheck = "Not delivered";
}

if (((pcode >= 2000) && (pcode <= 2599))||((pcode >= 2619) && (pcode <= 2899))||((pcode >= 2921) && (pcode <= 2999)))  {
    pstate = "NSW";
} else if ((pcode >= 1000) && (pcode <= 1999))  {
    pstate = "NSW LVR/PO Box";
} else if (((pcode >= 2600) && (pcode <= 2618))||((pcode >= 2900) && (pcode <= 2920))) {
    pstate = "ACT";
} else if ((pcode >= 200) && (pcode <= 299)) {
    pstate = "ACT LVR/PO Box";
} else if ((pcode >= 3000) && (pcode <= 3999)) {
    pstate = "VIC";
} else if ((pcode >= 8000) && (pcode <= 8999)) {
    pstate = "VIC LVR/PO Box";
} else if ((pcode >= 4000) && (pcode <= 4999)) {
    pstate = "QLD";
} else if ((pcode >= 9000) && (pcode <= 9999)) {
    pstate = "QLD LVR/PO Box";
} else if ((pcode >= 5000) && (pcode <= 5799)) {
    pstate = "SA";
} else if ((pcode >= 5800) && (pcode <= 5999)) {
    pstate = "SA LVR/PO Box";
} else if ((pcode >= 6000) && (pcode <= 6797)) {
    pstate = "WA";
} else if ((pcode >= 6800) && (pcode <= 6999)) {
    pstate = "WA LVR/PO Box";
} else if ((pcode >= 7000) && (pcode <= 7799)) {
    pstate = "TAS";
} else if ((pcode >= 7800) && (pcode <= 7999)) {
    pstate = "TAS LVR/PO Box";
} else if ((pcode >= 800) && (pcode <= 899)) {
    pstate = "NT";
} else if ((pcode >= 900) && (pcode <= 999)) {
    pstate = "NT LVR/PO Box";
} else {
    pcheck = "This is not a post code.";
    pstate = "No state.";
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = pcheck;
document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = pstate;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how to streamline this would be great. Again, I'm quite new to JS so any help would be great!

Comment: Why? What is wrong with using an array?

Comment: yeah look into FileReader and a CSV parser. might be a one-stop tool too.

Comment: Are you using any type of server-side rendering tool? Remember that JavaScript runs on the client machine, so it will not have access to the file system on the server.

Comment: There are actually 100s of Post Codes that get updated and we need to remove postcodes after 90 days (the report can be delivered daily). This page will reside in SharePoint and the .txt file will also sit it the same directory.

Comment: @CalvinBelden you can access files and even folders using JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you involve the server, then you have a lot of options.

The simplest way I can think to accomplish exactly what you're asking, which it seems is to just parse a text or csv file once loaded into the browser, would be:

(1) Make an AJAX request for the text file, and the simplest way to do that, for someone new to Javascript, is probably [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

(2) The .txt file will just be a string, so you could do:

```
var lines = file.split('\n');
```

`lines` will then be an array, that you can process as you wish in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CSV file. Then you can make a parser function for it after load string on the CSV file with ajax e.g: `$.get('post_code.csv',function(data){ var csv_to_array=parserFunction(data);})`.

I have made an example code for you. Please take a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/6gC7TopyhZ7cEZLxXFx3?p=preview. Please try to 'Run' and click 'CSV to Array' button on the right view to see how it works. The point of those code is:

1. Load string of CSV file named `post_code.csv` with ajax by using `$.get()` (jQuery function). The example of CSV file i have made using a simple comma (',') separator, as i think it will be save to separate each post code data. You can find post_code.csv file example on the left sidebar.
2. Parse the string of CSV file with my simple CSV string parser called `bexplode()` there, by using `var csv_to_array=bexplode(data, ',')`.

For more complex CSV format, i suggest you using more advance CSV parser like http://papaparse.com/ . But for your case, i think my function will be fine.